# How to use ReWriteBase in this scenario?

Tags: php, .htaccess, debugging, mod-rewrite

Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~new/

</IfModule>
```

Directory structure of my website is this:

[image]

Now what I want to do is to be able to visit paths like following:
`domain.com/~new/pages/page1.php`

But when I try to visit above `URL` I get redirected to `404 page`.
What am I missing? Are `ReWriteRule` also needed?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteBase` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, by itself it does nothing. `RewriteBase` is only necessary if you have relative path substitutions in your `RewriteRule`. And if you aren't doing that (ie. you are using root-relative or absolute paths) then you don't actually need it.

> Are ReWriteRule also needed?

Yes, `RewriteRule` is what actually does the URL rewriting. And you need to do some URL rewriting.

So, basically, you want to *internally rewrite* your URLs from:
`example.com/~new/pages/page1.php` (Your "virtual" URL)
to `example.com/pages/page1.php` (The *real* URL)

```
RewriteRule ^~new/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

The `(.*)` captures everything after `/~new/` and `$1` is a backreference to this captured subpattern.